# How to update MARKETING_VERSION and CFBundleVersion from plist file?

Tags: ios, swift, plist, xcode13, xcode14

I have a simple project and I want to update the project version and build number values from info.plist. I have added this `Bundle version string (short)` and `Bundle version` in `plist` file but its value is not reflected in the build.

But if I tried to change the same value from `Target>Info>Custom iOS Target Propeties` its working.

Is there any way I use `plist` to maintain my versions? or I'm missing something here?

**`info.plist`**

[image]

**Target Info**

[image]

I'm using Xcode 13.4.1 and 14.0

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Xcode is replacing your Info.plist file with one generated from project settings. Try setting "NO" to Your Project -> Build Settings -> Packaging -> Generate Info.plist File

Comment: Yes, I found that but forgot to post the answer here. Anyway thanks